# Limit and offset in laravel scout

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-scout

I am using scout for my api so can't use pagination , where as the scout only provides the pagination only so are there any ways to use offset and limit in laravel scout?

Answer (score 5):

U can use method take()

```
$result = YourModel::search('query')->take(20)->raw()
```

or

```
$result = YourModel::search('query')->take(20)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pagination is built into scout...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#pagination

Comment: you cannot achieve what the question is asking here with the pagination helper.